# curl to post data to google spreadsheet

Tags: curl, google-docs-api

while trying to post data to google sheet I am getting

```
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded is not a valid input type.
```

I am trying this command on terminal

```
curl -X POST -d '<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended"><gsx:First>first name</gsx:First><gsx:Last>last name</gsx:Last></entry>' https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0ArtbScpxn-LHdFQxQzJ3dDN2bEx2REFhYmo3UUxWUWc/od6/public/basic
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd go ahead and submit my findings. The following curl command posts to my test google form.

```
curl -S -v -X POST --location https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1kqn-xxJeVL4ftczABTIHjonhlf9YUOUlMpsxzFT8Fok/formResponse \
-d entry.1915510022=curl \
-d entry.1382424262=ChriChri \
-d entry.1376741077=chriRoro%40um.com \
-d entry.1604030572=UM 
-d entry.561632175=743-555%2B6321 \
-d entry.655897781=Yetassisi \ 
-d entry.227031813=coment+comanet \
-d entry.345486329=Yes
```

As far I can tell, you need to set the --location, -X POST, and add the form data using -d entries. The easiest way I found was to open Chrome dev-tools to the Network tab, and make a test submission using the normal form. Then you can see the -d entries and the URL --location. Note. I added the backslashes and returns but on OSX these will need to be removed for the command work in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Source: http://exhibita.com/blog/post/2009/09/10/Using-Google-Spreadsheets-to-Collect-Form-Data.aspx

```
   1: //In order to post to Google Spreadsheet Form
   2: //http://spreadsheets.google.com/formResponse?formkey=dFdYSTlzUVJsSomeReallyLongKeyGoesHereqemU2YUE6MA..
   3: //Name "entry.0.single" 
   4: //Email is "entry.1.single"
   5: //Phone is "entry.2.single"
   6: //Comment is "entry.3.single"
   7: //IP address is "entry.4.single"
   8: $url = 'http://spreadsheets.google.com/formResponse?formkey=dFdYSTlzUVJsSomeReallyLongKeyGoesHereqemU2YUE6MA..';
   9: // Create post array to send results to Google Spreadsheets
  10: $fields = array(
  11:                         'entry.0.single'=>urlencode($name),
  12:                         'entry.1.single'=>urlencode($email),
  13:                         'entry.2.single'=>urlencode($phone),
  14:                         'entry.3.single'=>urlencode($comments),
  15:                         'entry.4.single'=>getRealIpAddr(),
  16:                         'submit'=>'submit'
  17:                 );
  18:  
  19: // Begining of code for posting to Google Spreadsheet
  20: $fields_string = '';
  21: //url-ify the data for the POST
  22: foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
  23: //rtrim($fields_string,"& ");
  24: $fields_string = substr($fields_string, 0, strlen($fields_string)-1); 
  25: $result = "Fields_String: [" . $fields_string . "]<br />";
  26:  
  27: //set POST variables for Google Spreadsheets
  28: //open connection
  29: $ch = curl_init();
  30:  
  31: //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
  32: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  33: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
  34: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
  35: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  36: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
  37:  
  38: //execute post
  39: $result .= "Curl Results: [" . curl_exec($ch) . "]<br />";
  40:  
  41: //close connection
  42: curl_close($ch);
```

Of course this is using php and curl, I presume it should not be too tough to do from the terminal. 
Just my $0.02.